# Create a data frame in R from many XML files

Tags: r, dplyr, xml2

I am trying to retrieve some xml data with Swedish election statistics and create a data frame in R out of it, but I'm not that familiar with xml files can't get out the information I want. I've seen some other questions on how to create a data frame from many XML files, but they have a simpler structure than the data I'm working with.

The data is published as a zipped folder with many XML files. It can be read through the following R code:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

tf <- tempfile(tmpdir = tdir <- tempdir())
download.file("https://data.val.se/val/val2014/valnatt/valnatt.zip", tf)
xml_files <- unzip(tf, exdir = tdir)
```

The folder contains files for each of the 290 municipalities (files with 4 digit codes) and each election type, where the final letter in the filename indicate the type of election (R=national parliament, L=county council, K=municipal council). It also contains 3 XML files for total results for each of the three election types. The XML files with municipal data have the following structure (lines deleted for clarity):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/html"?>
    <!DOCTYPE VAL PUBLIC "-//Valmyndigheten//DTD Valresultat parti kommun 1.5//SV" "http://www.val.se/dtd/resultat/parti_kommun_1_5.dtd">
    <VAL TILLFÄLLE="Allmänna val 14 september 2014" FILNAMN="valnatt_0114R.xml" RAPPORTERING="VALNATTSRAPPORTERING" VALTYP="Riksdagsval" VALDAG="20140914" VALDAG_FGVAL="20100919" TID_RAPPORT="20140916105203">
      <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="M" BETECKNING="Moderaterna" FÄRG="#66BEE6" />
      <KOMMUN KOD="0114" NAMN="Upplands Väsby" TYP="Summering" KLARA_VALDISTRIKT="22" ALLA_VALDISTRIKT="22" RÖSTER="23638" RÖSTER_FGVAL="22215" TID_RAPPORT="20140914230336" MODNR="117144935">
        <GILTIGA PARTI="M" RÖSTER="6748" RÖSTER_FGVAL="8201" PROCENT="28,5" PROCENT_FGVAL="36,9" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="-8,4"/>
        <GILTIGA PARTI="C" RÖSTER="901" RÖSTER_FGVAL="891" PROCENT="3,8" PROCENT_FGVAL="4,0" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="-0,2"/>
        <KRETS_KOMMUN KOD="011401" NAMN="Norra valkretsen" TYP="Summering" KLARA_VALDISTRIKT="12" ALLA_VALDISTRIKT="12" RÖSTER="11907" RÖSTER_FGVAL="11202" TID_RAPPORT="20140914222651" MODNR="117118974">
          <GILTIGA PARTI="M" RÖSTER="3083" RÖSTER_FGVAL="3860" PROCENT="25,9" PROCENT_FGVAL="34,5" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="-8,6"/>
          <GILTIGA PARTI="C" RÖSTER="440" RÖSTER_FGVAL="431" PROCENT="3,7" PROCENT_FGVAL="3,8" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="-0,2"/>
      <VALDISTRIKT KOD="01140212" NAMN="Smedby Södra" RÖSTER="1201" RÖSTER_FGVAL="1186" TID_RAPPORT="20140914230336" MODNR="117144935">
        <GILTIGA PARTI="M" RÖSTER="227" RÖSTER_FGVAL="336" PROCENT="18,9" PROCENT_FGVAL="28,3" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="-9,4"/>
        <GILTIGA PARTI="C" RÖSTER="35" RÖSTER_FGVAL="17" PROCENT="2,9" PROCENT_FGVAL="1,4" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="+1,5"/>
        <GILTIGA PARTI="FP" RÖSTER="43" RÖSTER_FGVAL="61" PROCENT="3,6" PROCENT_FGVAL="5,1" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="-1,6"/>
        <ÖVRIGA_GILTIGA RÖSTER="20" RÖSTER_FGVAL="10" PROCENT="1,7" PROCENT_FGVAL="0,8" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="+0,8"/>
        <OGILTIGA TEXT="BLANK" RÖSTER="12" RÖSTER_FGVAL="13" PROCENT="1,0" PROCENT_FGVAL="1,1" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="-0,1"/>
        <OGILTIGA TEXT="OG" RÖSTER="13" RÖSTER_FGVAL="1" PROCENT="1,1" PROCENT_FGVAL="0,1" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="+1,0"/>
        <VALDELTAGANDE RÖSTBERÄTTIGADE="1551" RÖSTBERÄTTIGADE_KLARA_VALDISTRIKT_FGVAL="1546" SUMMA_RÖSTER="1226" SUMMA_RÖSTER_FGVAL="1200" PROCENT="79,0" PROCENT_FGVAL="77,6" PROCENT_ÄNDRING="+1,4"/>
      </VALDISTRIKT>
    </KRETS_KOMMUN>
  </KOMMUN>
</VAL>
```

Now, I would like for each file to get the data within all the `VALDISTRIKT` nodes and below and create a data frame. I'm not sure how to best structure such a data frame, but the following structure would suffice, where `GROUP` contain PARTI within GILTIGA, TEXT within OGILTIGA and just ÖVRIGA_GILTIGA within ÖVRIGA_GILTIGA. If possible, I also would like to add PROCENT and PROCENT_FG_VAL from within VALDELTAGANDE as variables (with the same information for each row within one VALDISTRIKT).

```
    KOD      NAMN             GROUP        RÖSTER RÖSTER_FG_VAL PROCENT PROCENT_FG_VAL PROCENT_FÖRÄNDRING
    01140212 "Smedby Södra"   M              227   336            18,9   18,3           -9,4
    01140212 "Smedby Södra"   C              35    17             2,9     1,4           +1,5
    01140212 "Smedby Södra"   FP             43    61             3,6     5,1           -1,6
    01140212 "Smedby Södra"   ÖVRIGA_GILTIGA 20    10             1,7     0,8           +0,8       
    01140212 "Smedby Södra"   BLANK          12    13             1,0     1,1           -0,1
    01140212 "Smedby Södra"   OG             13    1              1,1     0,1           +1,0
```

This information should be retrieved from each VALDISTRIKT in each of the 290 files with a name with 4 digits and end with a R. I guess I should loop over those files, or maybe rather use `map_df`?

I understand that this is a lot to ask in a question, and I'm sorry if I'm not using the correct terms for parts of an XML file, but if you could give me some pointers on how to get the information from the xml files into a data frame or where I could read more about how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to take a few steps forward. For one file, I can get all the information into two separate data frames using the following code, where top includes data about the district and below includes election results. I now just have to find a way to combine the two and adjust the code to read all the files.

```
top <- xml_find_all(t, "//VALDISTRIKT")
top <- top %>% 
        map(xml_attrs) %>% 
        map_df(~as.list(.))
below <- xml_find_all(t, "//VALDISTRIKT/*")
below <- p2 %>% 
    map(xml_attrs) %>% 
    map_df(~as.list(.))
```

All the best, R

Comment: I'm not familiar with R's XML packages but with XPath and XQuery, two programming languages to query XML documents. To query an XML document directly you need an XML editor, for example BaseX (www.basex.org). The following query gets you all KOD attribute values as well as all PARTI values (the string-join argument can easily by applied to any other variables you may be interested, using the same syntax) `for $val in //VALDISTRIKT
return
concat($val/@KOD,' ', string-join($val//@PARTI,' '))`

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll keep trying with R for now but good to know that there are other alternatives other there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer in [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/generate-a-data-frame-from-many-xml-files/10214) and I thought I might add it here as well, in case it might be of any help for anyone else.

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

# Make a temporary file (tf) and a temporary folder (tdir)
tf <- tempfile(tmpdir = tdir <- tempdir())

# Download the zip file 
download.file("https://data.val.se/val/val2014/valnatt/valnatt.zip", tf)

# Unzip it in the temp folder
xml_files <- unzip(tf, exdir = tdir)

# Get the filenames of the files to import
# They have 4 digits in the file name, and ends with the letter K
files_to_import <- fs::dir_ls(tdir) %>%
    str_subset(pattern = "valnatt_\\d{4}K.xml$")

# Create a function to read a file and get the information wanted
read_dist <- . %>% 
    read_xml() %>% 
    xml_find_all(., "//VALDISTRIKT") %>% 
    map_dfr(~ {
        # extract the attributes from the parent tag as a data.frame
        parent <- xml_attrs(.x) %>% enframe() %>% spread(name, value)
        # make a data.frame out of the attributes of the kids
        kids <- xml_children(.x) %>% map_dfr(~ as.list(xml_attrs(.x)))
        # combine them (bind_cols does not repeat parent rows)
        cbind.data.frame(parent, kids) %>% set_tidy_names() %>% as_tibble() 
    })
# Map over all the files
df <- map_df(files_to_import, read_dist)
```